# How to install XBMC on Xbox classic that boots into "Xbox Live"

Tags: kodi, xbox360

I have an Xbox classic (not 360) that I use as a HTPC using XBMC. But today a rogue application activated "Xbox Live" mode, which updated the system to boot into Xbox Live instead of XBMC. I have no idea what Xbox Live is - I don't use the Xbox for gaming, only as a HTPC for media. So how do I get XBMC back on the Xbox?

All instructions I've seen seem to start with "use FTP" - but the Xbox Live dashboard doesn't appear to have an FTP server.

Comment: I realize gaming console and gaming questions are not allowed on the site, but I've seen other XBMC questions, and in this case I just happen to run XBMC on an Xbox as opposed to a more modern system. I hope it's OK.

Comment: BTW, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_Live

Comment: @Nathaniel Thanks. I guess this is the default dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. How did you configure your xbox in the first place? Did you install a modchip, or was it a softmod? If you had it done it was probably a softmod. This means you must redo the software modification. There are many [tutorials](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-softmod-your-xbox...for-FREE/) out there. I have done this myself, it's tricky but certainly doable.

Comment: yeah sounds like an update (usually a retail game disc) blatted your dashboard, so you'll need to restore the softmod dashboard

Comment: @geocoin @edoode This was exactly the problem, thanks! To make matters worse, my DVD player wasn't working, so I had to get a new one. I didn't know games could blat my dashboard.